# MacBook Pro not receiving iMessages but can receive text messages

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, messages, apple-id

I swapped out my MacBook Air for a MacBook Pro (I installed it using Migration Assistant) a few days ago. After setting it up, I noticed I can't receive iMessages on my Macbook but can receive regular text messages.

My MacBook Pro is running Sonoma 14.2.1. In **Messages > Preferences > iMessages**, I have **Enable Messages in iCloud** checked and I'm logged in using the same Apple ID as my phone. Under **You can be reached for messages at:** both my number and Apple ID are checked.

Can someone advise what to do here?